# Bringing Data from CSV File into HighCharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have a bar chart visualization in Highcharts and I created the visualization by entering the data manually (look at my code at the bottom where I enter the values). I want to be able to include some function that can get data from a CSV file that is stored locally like for instance, in the 'Documents' Folder of my computer. Is it possible to get the CSV file locally from my computer and bring it into JS fiddle? If not, let's say the CSV file is stored on my google drive account. Is there an API that I can use (and load in the HTML section in JS fiddle) that will allow me to select a desired CSV File and load it? The CSV file will have 3 columns: Category (which is the number of visits (1, 2, .... 29+)), Q1 / 18 (TTM) Annual Guest Value, and Days Between 1st and 2nd Visits for the corresponding Category. The function will extract the data from each column and put them in the proper areas of my code to make the chart.

I want to automatically bring in data so that I don't have to manually type in all the values to make a new visualization.

My current code is:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
 
  title: {
    text: null,
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11-17', '18-28', '29+'],

    title: {
      text: 'Visits Per Customer (TTM)'
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
   minorGridLineWidth: 0,     
    
    title: {
      text: 'Average Return Rate Overall: 64 Days',
      y: 10
    },
    
    labels: {
      overflow: 'justify'
      
    }
  },
  
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.0f} </b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
  
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -25,
    y: 5,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
   
    shadow: true
    
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Q1 / 18 (TTM) Annual Guest Value',
    data: [0, 96.6, 73.2, 60.3, 52.5, 46.6, 41.4, 37.5, 34.4, 31.9, 25.4, 17.0, 9.7],
    color: 'grey',
    // label color
    dataLabels: {
      style: {
        color: 'grey'
       
      }
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Days Between 1st and 2nd Visits',
    data: [23, 45, 65, 85, 105, 125, 144, 163, 179, 199, 258, 394, 847],
    color: 'green',
    // label color
    dataLabels: {
      style: {
        color: 'green'
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

How can I do something like this? I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes that's possible with `data.csv` and `data.csvUrl` [Api Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.csv)

Comment: I tried using "csv: " in my code and putting the data into the HTML section but I don't know how to change the rest of my code so that it actually runs properly. I tried csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML but I don't know what else I should do

Comment: And for google drive, should I be using an API? I would need access to my google drive account which might require an API. What is the HTML code to import this?

Comment: Look these [examples](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module). There is one for a html table.

Comment: Could you send us what you've done currently, and explain more precisely what problem do you have?